# Can the security of ECDSA be compromised by the chosen parameters?

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa

The recommended parameters for a secp256k1 ECDSA curve are:

(All values are in hexadecimal)

```
p = FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF 
    FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE FFFFFC2F
a = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
b = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000007
G = 02
    79BE667E F9DCBBAC 55A06295 CE870B07
    029BFCDB 2DCE28D9 59F2815B 16F81798 (compressed version)
n = FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE
    BAAEDCE6 AF48A03B BFD25E8C D0364141
h = 01
```

However, if I change any of those parameters and used them, then will the security of the trapdoor function be compromised significantly?

For example, I could use:

```
G = 02
    B3949141 E36A5EE6 22754219 A87D849B
    DC5EA332 F2944A03 1A585112 F05673EA  (compressed version)
```

as the value of $G$ to generate public keys instead of the recommended value of above.  Will the security of the trapdoor function - and subsequently, the public keys - be compromised significantly?

Comment: This site supports both MarkDown (that the formatting buttons generate) and MathJax / Latex. Please format your questions to the best of your abilities before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, I could use:

If the discrete log is already backdoored with the standard base point $G$, then changing the base to another point on the curve doesn't solve this issue.

Let you know that $G$ is backdoored and you changed the base to $G' \neq G$. Then the entity that created the backdoor can use this to find the private keys.

Let $P = [k]G'$ be a public key with the new base. The attacker solves Dlog of $G' = [a]G$ only once. Using this they forms $P = [ak]G$. This is in the backdoored base so that they can solve the discrete logairhtmm to find $ak$. Once $ak$ is found, extracting the secret key can be performed with a simple modular arithmetic $k = ak \cdot a^{-1} \bmod n$ where the $a^{-1}$ is the inverse of $a$ in the modulo $n$.

As a result, once you have a backdoored discrete logarithm, then the curve is not safe to use. It is all in one, if a base point has a trapdoor then all base points have trapdoors!

> However, if I change any of those parameters and used them, then will the security of the trapdoor function be compromised significantly?

Changing the parameters $p,a$, and $b$ that defines $n$ and $h$, except the basepoint, change the curve and the new curve needs to be extensively analyzed;

1. Does the curve order has a prime or has a large prime factor?
2. Does the twist of the curve have large prime order?
3. Does it have a safe discrete log?
4. ...

These are the basics, more on this see [safecurves](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/index.html)

Comment: So changing the base point G will not have any effect on the security, however, changing any other parameter will?

Comment: Yes, changing $G$ doesn't have an effect, changing the curve parameters $(p,a,b)$ will define a new curve and that needs to be analyzed. A random curve doesn't need to be a safe curve.

Comment: @kelaka Your answers prove that the discrete log relative to different generators is hard, up to solving a single discrete log. However, given that we don't have a full reduction of ECDSA to discrete log, it is theoretically possible that ECDSA is easy for some $G'$ and not for others. Furthermore, if $G'$ is chosen in a special way and such that its discrete log relative to $G$ isn't known, then theoretically this could break ECDSA. There may be another proof, and in practice my guess would be that you're right, but this doesn't prove it.

Comment: @YehudaLindell thanks for the enlightening comment.