# If we can solve discrete log with on $\frac{1}{poly(n)}$ instances, then we can solve, with high probability, for all instances

Tags: discrete-logarithm, group-theory

I am trying to prove the following:

> Given an ensemble $\{p_n, g_n\}$ ($p_n$ is an $n$-bit prime and $g_n \in \mathbb{Z}^*_{p_n}$ is a generator), if $A$ is a deterministic polynomial time algorithm such that:
>
> $$ \Pr_{x \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}^*_{p_n}} [A(a)=x \text{  where  }
> g_n^x=a]=\frac{1}{poly(n)}$$
>
> then there is a PPT algorithm $A'$ that solves discrete log with high probability for this ensemble.

I would probably need to somehow call $A$ a polynomial number of times and use the results, but I have no concrete direction on how to proceed with this intuition to define $A'$. Obviously, I can verify the response by $A$, since computing $g^x$ can be done in polynomial time, but if it's wrong - then what?

Note, I have seen all sorts of questions on discrete log using something called baby step giant step, but I am not familiar with that at all (in case it may be useful here).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [If there is a backdoor to any base then there is a backdoor to all bases](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/91545/18298). Quite easy to see this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the discrete logarithm is random self reduceable, that is the worst case is as hard as the random case.

If we are given y and wish to find $x$ s.t $y=g^x \bmod p$
we can pick a random a and calculate b=$g^a\times y =g^{a+x}$

This value $b$ is uniformly distributed regardless of y. If however, we solve a discrete logarithm for it we can easily subtract $a$ and find $x$.

Q.E.D.